# Cannot determine what property value is empty?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

When running AWS CloudFormation with the below template(part of a pre-existing nested stack), I am getting a failure that "Property Value cannot be empty." for both of the lambda items I am trying to create CloudWatch alarms for.  I have tried to run it as part of the nested stack as well as the template by itself to no avail.  Can anyone offer any insight?

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Description": "Creation of CloudWatch Alarms",
    "Resources": {
        "CLFirstLambdaAlarm": {
            "Type": "AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm",
            "Properties": {
                "AlarmName": "CLFirstLambdaErrors",
                "AlarmDescription": "Alarms when an error occurs on the first lambda",
                "AlarmActions": [{ "Ref": "AlarmNotificationTopic" }],
                "MetricName": "Errors",
                "Namespace": "AWS/Lambda",
                "Dimensions": [{
                        "Name": "first-lambda"
                    },
                    {
                        "Value": { "Fn::ImportValue": "CLFirstLambda" }
                    }
                ],
                "ComparisonOperator": "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold",
                "EvaluationPeriods": "1",
                "Period": "60",
                "Unit": "Count",
                "Statistic": "Sum",
                "Threshold": "1",
                "TreatMissingData": "notBreaching"
                    }
        },
        "CLSecondLambdaAlarm": {
            "Type": "AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm",
            "Properties": {
                "AlarmName": "CLSecondLambdaErrors",
                "AlarmDescription": "Alarms when an error occurs on the second lambda",
                "AlarmActions": [{ "Ref": "AlarmNotificationTopic" }],
                "MetricName": "Errors",
                "Namespace": "AWS/Lambda",
                "Dimensions": [{
                        "Name": "second-lambda"
                    },
                    {
                        "Value": { "Fn::ImportValue": "CLSecondLambda" }
                    }
                ],
                "ComparisonOperator": "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold",
                "EvaluationPeriods": "1",
                "Period": "60",
                "Unit": "Count",
                "Statistic": "Sum",
                "Threshold": "1",
                "TreatMissingData": "notBreaching"
            }
        },
        "AlarmNotificationTopic": {
            "Type": "AWS::SNS::Topic",
            "Properties": {
                "TopicName": "cl-alarm-topic",
                "Subscription": [{
                "Endpoint": "me@domain.com",
                "Protocol": "email"
                }]
            }
        }
    },
    "Outputs": {
        "AlarmNotificationTopicArn": {
            "Description": "ARN of AlarmNotificationTopic",
            "Value": { "Ref" : "AlarmNotificationTopic" },
            "Export": { "Name" : "AlarmNotificationTopic" }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be able to at least for which resource it fails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [CloudFormation Linter](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cfn-python-lint/) gives more detailed error messages:

```
E3003 Property Value missing at Resources/CLFirstLambdaAlarm/Properties/Dimensions/0
template.json:13:30

E3003 Property Name missing at Resources/CLFirstLambdaAlarm/Properties/Dimensions/1
template.json:16:19

E3003 Property Value missing at Resources/CLSecondLambdaAlarm/Properties/Dimensions/0
template.json:37:30

E3003 Property Name missing at Resources/CLSecondLambdaAlarm/Properties/Dimensions/1
template.json:40:19
```

[`AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cw-alarm.html)

[`AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm.Dimension`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cw-dimension.html)

---

Try these `AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm.Dimensions` properties instead:

```
              "Dimensions": [{
                      "Name": "first-lambda",
                      "Value": { "Fn::ImportValue": "CLFirstLambda" }
                  }
              ],


              "Dimensions": [{
                      "Name": "second-lambda",
                      "Value": { "Fn::ImportValue": "CLSecondLambda" }
                  }
              ],
```